# why I get blue-effect when use opencv on android?

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat

my english is bad)
i'm use opencv v2.4.2

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mDefaultPath + name_s + type);
Bitmap mBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false); 

Mat s_image = new Mat(); 
Utils.bitmapToMat(mBitmap,s_image);
Mat rgb0 = new Mat();
Mat o_image = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint points = new MatOfKeyPoint();

FeatureDetector surf0 = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
surf0.detect(s_image, points);

Log.d(TAG, "Sum of keypoints "+points.toList().size());

Imgproc.cvtColor(s_image, rgb0, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
Features2d.drawKeypoints(rgb0, points, rgb0);

Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb0, o_image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

Utils.matToBitmap(o_image, mBitmap);
Highgui.imwrite(mDefaultPath + name_o + type, o_image);
```

after this manipulations i get normall image on screen (on ImageView), but in my file on sdcard i get image with blue-effect
i think problem in convert bitmap to map, or rgba to rgb and back

can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`imwrite` function expects BGR order of channels in passed image.

Comment: Please post your solution instead of just saying it's working.

Comment: The relevant code is:
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mBgra, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);